# Extract Elevation data from DEM and add Z-Values to Polyline file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, elevation, feature-extraction

Is there an efficient way to add elevation data from a DEM Raster to a polyline shapefile?

I am attempting to add elevation data to a city roads shapefile to map out flash flooding issues. The streets network is huge and there is flash flooding issues in many places, so I am looking for a way to do this all at once rather than small lines at once.

Answer (score 1):

The add surface information tool in the 3D Analyst toolbox will add surface information to a vector file.  [See this link](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/3d-analyst/add-surface-information.htm) for tool documentation.  These tools (like most raster-vector tools) require the raster and vector data share a coordinate reference system.  In ArcGIS failing to do so would return a 99999 error code (unknown).  I don't know if they fixed that error message in Pro with an actual error code..